# Mixed effects ordinal regression: CLMM (ordinal) with non-proportional odds?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordinal-data

I have Likert scale responses (DV) from a survey rating 10 voices on 10 personality traits. I need to run a regression model in R to look at the effect of accent and some other participant demographic data (all categorical, one ordinal) on these Likert responses.

I initially used clmm() from package ordinal to run a model as follows:

```
status.mm<-clmm(response ~ stimulus.accent +
                 age.group + gender + ethnicity + (1|ID), 
               data = status, na.action=na.fail)
```

In order to test the proportional odds/parallel lines assumption, I found some questions on here indicating I need to remove the random effect, replicate my model using clm() and run nominal_test() on the model. (personally think this isn't ideal, I'd rather test the model with the random intercepts, but I couldn't find another way - please let me know if there is one!!)

This model failed (specifically, stimulus.accent did not pass the test of proportional odds, which is the main IV I'm interested in).

I've seen a few different options being talked about, but I've reached the limit of my understanding of how to run a model on this data that does not rely on the proportional odds assumption. Another key thing is that I need that random intercept of ID in my model, which discounts some of the options (e.g., using vglm() from VGAM package)

Options I've seen so far:

1. using mixor() from mixor package
2. using clmm2() and specifying `nominal = ~ stimulus.accent`
3. specifying `link='probit'` in clmm()

Q: What is the best way to do this, and what would the code look like? Please bear with me, I'm not a statistician and am self taught!

Comment: Though this doesn't deal with random effects it address the cost of **not** assuming proportional odds, plus some other issues: https://www.fharrell.com/post/impactpo ; you'll see some ways of assessing PO that may be relevant, e.g., AIC and adjusted $R^2$ may indicate that a PO model predicts better than a non-PO model.

Comment: Thanks for this Frank, I'm sure this will come in useful, but I'm sadly still not any closer to finding out *how* to run a model without PO assumption.

Comment: Consider the Bayesian partial proportional odds model with random effects: https://hbiostat.org/R/rmsb

Comment: Thank you - I've next to no Bayesian knowledge, so was trying to avoid this. May not be possible. Trying to understand whether it would be sensible to run a multinomial logistic regression model instead... or just ignore the failed assumption, if plotting the models provides sensible nearly proportional odds?

Comment: The "Impact of PO" article referenced above makes the point that it's a trade-off: there is a cost of making the PO assumption and a cost of not making it.  A polytomous model requires a huge number of parameters to be estimated in many cases, and there is a cost for each parameter.

Comment: I ignore if you already found an answer; if so, could you please share it here?
Also, I found something that might be helpful https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-March/349229.html
This person explains that we can test the assumption of parallel lines by comparing a model under the assumption of proportional odds and a model under the alternative hypothesis (i.e., non-proportional odds) and also provides an example of how to do it with syntaxes in R to fit both of the models:
Model under the assumption of PO: `m1 <- clm(rating ~ temp + contact, data=wine)`
Model under the assumption of N